# Using XSLT how do I add element around text before and after element in mixed content?

Tags: xslt

This is the structure of my XML-document:

```
<body><p>Some text <em>before</em> image<img src="" width="" height=""/>some text <b>after</b> image</p></body>
```

After processing it should look like this:

```
<body><p>Some text <em>before</em> image</p><img src="" width="" height=""/><p>some text <b>after</b> image</p></body>
```

How can I add the p elements to the text before and after an img element?

Comment: Which version of XSLT do you use? And one example doesn't really explain the requirements. In your sample the `img` element is child of a `p` element, are these the two relevant elements that needs to work for or is that a task for any container element of `img` elements? At least for XSLT 2/3 this seems like a grouping problem similar to the spec example on `group-adjacent`, so check https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info

Comment: I'm with @MartinHonnen here. It looks like you want a rule for `p` elements that  group adjacent childs by boolean `self::img` key, wrapping the `current-group()` with another `p` or not choosing by the `current-grouping-key()`.

Comment: I'm using XSLT version 2.0. This was exactly what I needed! You were correct that all the img elements that I needed to transform are only children of a p element. My XSLT experience is beginner level but this gives me a better understanding of current-grouping-key() and current-group() functions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="p[img]">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::img)">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::img">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <p><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></p>
      </
    </
  </
</
```